# JAVASCRIPT/AJAX reload a page if cookie exists else stay on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

I code mainly serverside with PHP and I ran into a situation where I need to reload the page based on user input. I set a cookie "reload" with value "1" and need a javascript or AJAX to check for it in real time. If the cookie exists, this script needs to trigger the event

```html
window.location.href="samplepage.php"
```

I am really new here so hope this question is in right forum. Thanks for any help!

Comment: you can use setInterval to query for the cookie

Comment: Is the cookie being set via ajax or something?

Comment: nope, cookie is being set via another php page that is embedded in the site by Iframe. Both sites are in same domain/folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('reload') > -1 ) {
  window.location.href="samplepage.php" ;
}
```

Comment: sorry this didnt seem to work, i need a script to recheck it ever 1-5 seconds if the cookie is present and if so, it needs to reload the page